# JoltTransform to assign any one value to one key

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have some incoming data in form of json. But the key might differ message to message. For example department.org.id or department.id represents the same value department.id.

I tried implementing with SHIFT transform but it only picks up the departmentId and wont load the remaining fields. I do not want to overwrite all other values in the json. But there are a few other fields where in I need this behaviour. Also tried modify-overwrite but I am not sure how to access the value part.

**Update 2:**
I have added a more complicated version where in SourceSystem field can be accepted from either one of the values sourceSystem/originNotification.domain/receivedMetadata.domain. Is there any way this mapping could be done through JOLT or any other processor. I have many other fields which require this kind of mapping.

Attempt with modify-overwrite

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      // String join the values in the array x, with a comma and a space
      "employee.department.id": "@(employee.department.id)",
      "employee.department.id": "@(employee.department.org.id)"
    }
  }
]
```

Example 1:

```json
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "sourceSystem":"test",
    "department": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "management"
    }
  }
}
```

Example Message 2:

```json
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "department": {
      "org": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "management"
      }
    },
    "originNotification":{
       "domain":"test"
    }
  }
}
```

Example Message 3:

```json
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "organization": {
      "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "management"
      }
    },
    "receivedMetadata":{
        "domain":"test"
    }
  }
}
```

Output desired

```json
{
  "employee": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "department": {
        "organization":{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "management"
        }
    },
    "sourceSystem":"test"

  }
}
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan in nifi its only modify-overwrite or modify-default

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional to determine the **`department`** equals to **`org`** or **not** (eg.`"*"`) along with the other nodes for all possible input types such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "employee": {
        "*": "&1.&", // else case, eg. the elements other than "department"
        "department": {
          "org": {
            "@": "&3.&2.&1anization" // &1 stands for going up 1 level and copying the literal "org"              
          },
          "*": { // else case for the node "department"
            "@": "&3.&2.organization.&" // &3 stands for going up 3 levels and copying the literal "employee"
          }
        },
        "organization": {
          "*": "&2.&.&1"
        },
        "r*M*|o*N*": {
          "domain": "&2.sourceSystem"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: is there any other way to assign different values to the same field in Jolt or in Nifi ? Because for some other field in the json it could be like customer.item.id or item.id should be assigned to the same key item.id. Only one of these values would come in, so I can skip the cardinality operation

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to have trough editing the question by adding an example @Scorpy

Comment: I have updated the question with the complicated examples too now, could you please guide if this is possible with Jolt ? @Barbaros

Comment: OK, I've just edited @Scorpy